# Null-terminating a string in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm writing  `strncpy` in MIPS, but I'm having trouble null-terminating the string. If i do not null-terminate it myself, the string goes on and on. I have tried `sb $__ 0($0)` but that does not seem to work...

`$a0 = pointer to destination array`
`$a1 = source string`
`$a2 = number of characters to copy`

```
strncpy: 
    add $t1 $zero $zero  #counter 
    beq $a2 $0 done # if num chars to copy is 0, return.
    j cpyLoop

cpyLoop:    

    beq $t1 $a2 done # if counter == num to copy, end
    lb $t2 0($a1) # load the character
    beq $t2 $0 done #if we reach the null char, end
    sb $a0 0($a1)
    addi $a0 $a0 1 #increment the pointer in dest array
    addi $a1 $a1 1 #increment the pointer in source array
    addi $t1 $t1 1 #increment the counter
    j cpyLoop



done:   
    lb $a0 0(0)
    move $v0 $a0 
    jr $ra
```

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021210/strncpy-in-mips-has-a-weird-behavior

Comment: _"I have tried `sb $__ 0($0)`"_. Trying to write to address 0 is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make this post complete i will take part of coat from the dublicate poast mentioned above and complete it:

```
addi $a3 $a0 0


strncpy:   
        beqz $a2, out
        lb $t0, 0($a1)      #load byte
        beqz $t0 out 
        subiu $a2, $a2, 1
        sb $t0, 0($a0)
        addiu $a0, $a0, 1
        addiu $a1, $a1, 1
        j strncpy


 out:
        move $a0 $a3
        move $v0 $a0
        jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

Null-terminating a string is a matter of writing a `0` byte to the terminating offset in the string.

Your attempt, `lb $a0 0(0)` *loads* a byte, but because null termination entails writing, you probably meant `sb`. Using `0(0)` as the address doesn't make much sense, nor does `$a0` as the source register since it contains an address.

The correct version is `sb $zero ($a0)`. This writes a `0` byte to the offset at `$a0` which conveniently points to the tail of the string, either due to encountering the null terminator in the source string or the count expiring, whichever is first.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```
.data
dst: .space 12
src: .asciiz "hello world"
.text
main:
    la $a0 dst      # destination string
    la $a1 src      # source string
    li $a2 5        # number of chars to copy
    jal strncpy

    # print the destination string
    la $a0 dst
    li $v0 4
    syscall

    # print '\n'
    li $a0 10
    li $v0 11
    syscall

    li $v0 10
    syscall

strncpy:
    li $t0 0        # index

strncpy_loop:
    # while counter < chars to copy || src[i] != '\0'
    beq $t0 $a2 strncpy_done
    lb $t1 ($a1)    # load src[i]
    beqz $t1 strncpy_done

    sb $t1 ($a0)    # dst[i] = src[i]
    addi $t0 $t0 1  # i++
    addi $a0 $a0 1  # dst++
    addi $a1 $a1 1  # src++
    b strncpy_loop

strncpy_done:
    sb $zero ($a0)  # dst[i] = '\0' null terminate dst
    move $v0 $a0
    jr $ra
```

---

Additional remarks regarding your code:

- `sb $a0 0($a1)` is incorrect; it's attempting to store an address as a byte (use `$t2` instead) and `$a1` is the source address, not the destination address.
- The precondition `beq $a2 $0 done # if num chars to copy is 0, return.` doesn't appear necessary. The loop termination conditional already checks this.
- `beq $t2 $0 done` can be simplified to `beqz $t2 done`.
- The first `j cpyLoop` isn't necessary since the loop is the next instruction with fallthrough anyway.